# Spherical harmonics orthogonality

Tags: integration, orthogonality, harmonic-functions, spherical-coordinates, spherical-harmonics

I've been struggling with this integral
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \sin(\theta) e^{-i\phi} Y_{l m}(\theta,\phi) Y^*_{l'm'}
(\theta,\phi) \mathrm d\theta \mathrm d\phi
$$
I've tried to use the definition of the spherical harmonics as
$$
Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi) = N P^m_l(\cos(\theta)) e^{i m \phi} 
$$
with $N$ being the normalization constant.

I was planning to use the orthogonality of the associated Legendre polynomials $P^n_l$ but I was unable to make any further progress. How do I go around solving the given integral?

Comment: Is it ${\rm d}\theta$? or ${\rm d}\cos \theta$

Comment: I see i forgot the $sin(\theta)$, edited, thank you.

Comment: Are $\phi$ and $\varphi$ supposed to be the same, or different?

Comment: The same, I'll edit that also